# Diode Clipper Circuit

Tags: diodes

Please help me understand this circuit

During the positive half cycle of the source, the diode will not conduct until the voltage divider voltage across diode and load resistor R(L) doesn't become 0.7 volts, so the charges flow towards the load resistor R(L) and there will be output voltage across the load resistor.

What confuses me is why the output voltage remains at 0.7 volts after that. Won't the voltage divider voltage increase more than 0.7 volts when the input source voltage is increasing?

I know that when the voltage divider voltage becomes 0.7 volts, the diode will become a short circuit but I am not getting that why the voltage divider voltage won't exceed more than 0.7 volts.

[image]

Comment: The diagram source needs to be cited. Either name the textbook you copied it for OR a web source. || That diagram can be found uobabylon.edu.iq/eprints/publication_12_4795_82.pdf  page 18 figure a. Check that that is indeed identical and, if so, you could cite it as a source. Note that this is a copyright issue AND a site rule which the moderators are not at liberty to waive.

Answer (score 3):

Why? Because it's just assumed to work in this way. It's only a widely used simplified way to think a diode, which in reality is more complex. As soon as any external circuit (see NOTE1) tries to lift the voltage over the diode higher than 0.7 volts, the diode sinks more current, so much more that the voltage stays at 0.7 V. That's for silicon PN diodes. Other diodes need other assumptions.

A real diode obeys a non-linear approximately logarithmic equation between the current and voltage, the "sink so much current that the voltage doesn't get higher than 0.7 V" is used in practical applications only because it often gives an approximated, but realistic view how a circuit works. For example I have hundreds of times searched  faults in electronic devices and checked with a multimeter or an oscilloscope do the approximately 0.7 V voltages over the diodes exist right.

The model is useless when one should take into the account the temperature, capacitive behaviour, breakdown effects (Zener, avalanche), light and, of course, the exact real relation (= a smooth curve) between the voltage over the diode and the current through it. For example a logarithmic amplifier is based on that smooth curve.

NOTE1: the voltage source + the voltage divider. Mathematical solution is possible for example by using the Thevenin equivalent of the external circuit. Harmfully the equations must generally be solved iteratively or graphically because the common logarithmic current vs voltage equation for diodes is unfriendly for algebraic methods.